# How to quantize a classical field? What are the basic assumptions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

I have learnt canonical quantization but I'm very confused about it. Because it seems that different textbooks do it in a different way although they all end up into the same result. I want to know a general (or at least relatively general) way to quantize a classical field with a given Lagrangian density. I think it is equivalent to know the basic assumptions when we do the canonical quantization. As far as I know, for Bose particles, the first assumption is we replace the field and its canonically conjugate field by operators. And assume that they satisfied the equal time commutation relations. Then we assume the dynamics of the field operator satisfies the Heisenberg's equation of motion: $$i*\dot{\psi}=[\psi,H].$$

Now, I have my first question: Can we derive the dynamics of the conjugate field \pi using the commutation relations and the definition of \pi? Or is it another assumption that cannot be derived.

Also, from this equation and the commutation relations we can get the equation of motion of the field (EOM). But this result can be different from the classical EOM from the variation of the action. Is it correct? If it is, does it mean the classical EOM is not valid after we do the quantization. Then is the definition that $$\pi=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\psi}}$$ still valid? If it is not true, they must be the same. How to prove it?

Finally, I think these are all the assumptions we need for Bose particles. Then we want to find the particle state solutions of the EOM and then use these solutions as a basis to expand the field operator and define the coefficients as the creation and annihilation operators.

My second question is: how do we get the expansion of the conjugate field \pi? Which one is correct?

1. Use the classical definition of \pi to derive the relation between \pi and \psi using the Lagrangian, and then derive the commutation relations of the creation and annihilation operators with the commutation relations of \psi and \pi. Here we assume the classical definition of \pi is still valid.
2. Treat the commutation relations of the creation and annihilation operators as assumptions, then use these relations and the commutation relations of \pi and \psi to derive the expression of the expansion of \pi. Here we didn't use the classical definition of \pi at all! Will this be in accordance with the first way and why?

If all the two ways above are wrong. Is there a standard method to do it?

Comment: General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: are you familiar with Poisson brackets?